# Is the remove method of Java's ArrayList Iterator O(n^2) or O(n)? when iterating over the list?

Tags: java, iterator, time-complexity

I'm iterating over an ArrayList using a while loop, and removing values in-place if they meet a certain criteria. My code is in the spirit of the following snippet:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int N = 1000
    // setup list to show as an example
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Date start = new Date();
    // iterate over entire list, removing half the values
    Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Integer in = iter.next();
        if (in % 2 == 0) {
            // is it even?
            iter.remove();
        }
    }

    Date end = new Date();
    System.out.println(end.getTime() - start.getTime());
    System.out.println(list.size());
```

What I want to know is if the time complexity of this iterator loop is O(N) or O(N^2). I believe it's O(N^2) because Java ArrayList's are backed on a regular array, and for each remove you must necessarily move O(N) of the subsequent values to the left to keep the array in a sane state.

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question. The time complexity of the remove method is documented. Th time complexity of your loop is computable by construction from the known time complexities of the iterator and the remove method.

Comment: It's larger than N, but it may not be N^2 if memory blocks can be copied efficiently.

Comment: Are you accounting for [amoritization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis)?

Comment: @EJP you mention the remove method's time complexity is documented but provide no link to the docs. I have not been able to find it myself, else I wouldn't ask here. Can you please reply with a link to the documentation?

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but if you're looking to improve performance, you'll get constant time if you use
 `LinkedList` instead.

Comment: And you can find the documentation for `ArrayList` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: You should not have to ask for a Javadoc link. From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): " The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking)." It's rather astonishing that you couldn't find that, or indeed the Javadoc itself.

Answer (score 1):

None of the replies to my question provide evidence of how Iterator.remove works, so I did my own testing. My personal testing leads me to believe that the time complexity is O(N^2). Here is data from 3 different tests, where each "Time" value is an average over 10 iterations:

N = 10,000
Time = 8ms

N = 100,000
Time = 487ms

N = 200,000
Time = 2026ms

a doubling of the list size results in a roughly 4 times longer runtime.